# Rendering inline SVGs without Webview

Tags: java, android, svg, kotlin, webview

Right now I'm using a RecyclerView, where each card is a WebView. I'm using WebViews to render inline SVG content, which most of the items in the list have. Rendering these SVG images inline is essential, and TextViews cannot handle this type of content.

The problem is that these WebViews do not perform well. If the user scrolls too fast, they can see graphical glitches or white spaces because the content has not yet been loaded into the WebView.

I have tried my best to improve the performance of loading each WebView in the list, but with no good results. At minimum, loading `<html></html>` into the WebViews cost 75ms each. Loading the inline SVG content can take between 150 and 200ms on average.

What can I do to:

(1) Render inline SVGs in the most performant way or

(2) Is there a way to improve the performance of using WebViews in a RecyclerView?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using an ImageView to hold the svg?

Comment: It's not just 1 SVG, but many SVGs inside of a HTML string

Comment: Sorry, but do you mind sharing an example of what the HTML string looks like so I can make sure I'm on the same page?

Comment: Sure - https://gist.github.com/Jonty800/1a76c6acde3d1f60305aef6c28877af7

Comment: Maybe it would help to export the SVGs from the HTML, preload them and then import them again as "finished" images? Maybe that saves some time. Not sure how the HTML code is handled, but if its only interpreted after the WebView is already visible, then maybe that helps